# google compute engine financial exposure limit

Tags: security, google-compute-engine

On google compute engine, how can I limit the network egress or total bill for each month.  I am concerned about possible security issues and want to limit my financial exposure.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to limit your usage in Compute Engine, unlike App Engine. However, you can use the [Detailed Usage Export](https://developers.google.com/compute/detailed-usage-export/) feature to generate reports that may be of help. You can create a script that will allow you to review this information.